# jenkins Job Status via Curl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to get job build status failure or success via curl command.
I tried this :

```
curl --silent http://user:TokenID@Jenkins-BuildURL/job/job_number/api/json | jq -r '.result'
```

Unable to execute the curl.

Comment: You should post more information, such as an error message, for example. In the command  you posted, the URL isn't surrounded in quotes, which would probably cause problems.

Comment: I tried with quotes - Its just giving me time spent
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:39 --:--:--

Comment: Add `-I` to see the headers. Seems it's returning no content (e.g. redirecting)

Answer (score 5):

Try below Command :

FYI , you are missing JOB_NAME in your curl command

```
  curl --silent http://user:TokenID@Jenkins-BuildURL/job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/api/json
```

Note : JOB_NAME,BUILD_NUMBER are jenkins Environment variables , when executed from jenkins job it will pick latest job details
and you can always pass your credentials using '-u' option :

Example :

```
curl --silent -u username:user_pwd http://Jenkins-BuildURL/job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/api/json
```

And simple trick would be first check in browser if the Url is valid or not , if it valid half of the problem is eliminated , then we can focus on curl command

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to execute it. I used --user username:APIToken.

Comment: @RCoder   can you vote up/accept the answer , so that other people who has the same question will be able to find the answer.